# Asp.Net not giving enough error info

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, elmah

I'm getting frustrated with this code, as I can't figure out what is happening.

My users occassionally get an error (I can't replicate it, as it works fine for me) when trying to edit a simple value on a webform:

```
Server Error in '/cp' Application.

Input string was not in a correct format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web                                                                       request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.  Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +13908045
System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +305
DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl.Internal.PopupWindowClientStateUtils.LoadClientState(PopupWindow window, String state) +288
DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl.ASPxPopupControl.LoadWindowsState(String state) +133
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.LoadPostDataInternal(NameValueCollection postCollection, Boolean raisePostDataEvent) +447
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +1068
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2773
```

It tells me that an exception has occurred, but not where, or why.

The PopUp box button to save the change to the deposit is:

```
 Protected Sub btnDepPaid_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDepPaid.Click
        Try
            ASPxPopupControl3.ShowOnPageLoad = False
            Dim da As New bsTableAdapters.DepositTableAdapter
            da.UpdateQuery(DepPaid.Text, CustID.Text)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

I have Elmah running, and all it shows is the error above - but I can't see how an error is not happening - as DepPaid.Text and CustID.Text, according to Elmah, have valid "Strings" eg: "65.00" in them.

My frustration is, the error isn't saying on which line the issue is, just that the "input string wasn't in the correct format" - how can I get it to give me more info?

Is there anything else I can add to the above code, to capture where the error is happening, or any other information that can pinpoint what the error actually is?

What is being input, according to Elmah is:

[image: ElmahInput]

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Enter 65,00 and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Looks like it failing during the convert call so perhaps like @Peri suggests try different variations especially as it seems to be currency related perhaps some users are typing in the currency symbol such as £ or $ etc.

Comment: Hi - thanks for that suggestion - 65,00 results in a validation error on the form, which doesn't allow it to be submitted.  I've also attached the string that is being entered, according to Elmah, which confirms it is a valid decimal (the users having the issue, have been using the app for a long time - I have changed nothing, and I know they are competent at making changes on the webform - so perhaps it is a browser issue, if they have upgraded recently for example??) - thanks again for any assistance/suggestions.

Comment: I see call to ParseInt32 uses NumberFormatInfo. Maybe it uses operating system's settings. In which case it could expect . or , as decimal separator. Maybe validation always demands . as a separator but code that parses input depends on system settings? Try changing separator in your system to ,

Comment: We're dealing with this as well. But it seems to be related to IE10 using DevExpress popups. Devexpress' recommendation is to upgrade.

Comment: Hi - yeah, I finally found that too - but I have an older version of the controls, and can't afford to keep the very high subscription current.  I've opted just to recode without using DevExpress tools - at least that way, any future updates to browsers, will only break my code, and I can easily (and affordably) resolve those.  Cheers, Mark